# Custom Adapter OnItemClick with multiple arrays

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```
public void populate(ArrayList<String> array, ArrayList<String> array2) {
            ListView showList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            SchedAdapter shows = new SchedAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.rowlayout, array, array2);
            showList.setAdapter(shows);
            showList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                        final int position, long id) {
                    final String selected = (String) parent
                            .getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });
        }
```

The `Toast` is showing the string in `array2` and I want it to show the string held in `array`.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void populate(ArrayList<String> array, ArrayList<String> array2) {
        ListView showList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        SchedAdapter shows = new SchedAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.rowlayout, array, array2);
        showList.setAdapter(shows);
        showList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                    final int position, long id) {

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), array2.get(position),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), array.get(position),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: That gives me the error: `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<String>`

Comment: Had to change `ArrayList<String> array` to `final ArrayList<String> array`.  Thank you, works now :)